# Basic angularjs ng-include not working wamp

Tags: angularjs, server

I'm currently learning angularJS.  I'm working with wamp for the server.  All other angularjs works until I reached `ng-include`.  All files are within www directory of the wamp server.  All linked files and the html are in the same directory.  Any ideas?

html main:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>Directives</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp", [])
            .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.todos = [
                    { action: "Get groceries", complete: false },
                    { action: "Call plumber", complete: false },
                    { action: "Buy running shoes", complete: true },
                    { action: "Buy flowers", complete: false },
                    { action: "Call family", complete: false }];
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">

    <ng-include src="'partial.html'"></ng-include>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the partial i'm linking to:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Done</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in todos" ng-class="$odd ? 'odd' : 'even'">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="prop in item">{{prop}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Errors:

```html
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/partial.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.angular.js:9827 (anonymous function)
angular.js:11607 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/partial.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:9827:11
    at sendReq (file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:9628:9)
    at serverRequest (file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:9344:16)
    at processQueue (file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:13189:27)
    at file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:13205:27
    at Scope.$eval (file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:14401:28)
    at Scope.$digest (file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:14217:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:14506:24)
    at bootstrapApply (file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/angular.js:1448:15)angular.js:11607 (anonymous function)
file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/bootstrap.css.map Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///C:/wamp/www/angular-server/chapter%2010/bootstrap-theme.css.map Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Yeah there are actually...looks like a problem with the ajax request maybe?  I'll post above for clarity.

Comment: Sorry...updated w/ correct.  Previous was from a separate example provided by the teaching source which also doesn't work.

Comment: Weird.. it complains about cross origin. But you are trying to fetch it from the same somain right? What's the URL of your site ?

Comment: It's hosted locally on the wamp server...in the www directory.  Name of the main html calling the partial is "example.html"

Comment: You need to start the wamp server and go to `127.0.0.1/` and navigate to your project. This is because you aren't actually using wamp right now, it's just in the www directory.

Comment: Bingo...thanks.  I thought because the rest of the angularjs was working I was operating under it already.